# How to remove event "selectable" of jQueryUI with javaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is my problem: i've got this:

```
$("table").selectable({
    filter: "td",    
    start: function()
    {
```

so, every `td` and every `tr` are "Selectable", but, i did something like this:

```
selecting: function(){
if(posicionInicial.posy == arregloObjetos[1].posy) //Esta seleccionando por columnas
                {
                    if(direccionSeleccion.posy != posicionInicial.posy)
                    {                            
                        $(".ui-selectee").unbind();    
                    }                        
                }
```

}

i want to "unbind" the event of the "Selectable" of other "td"s that are not in the same row or column... (Please, remember that i need to cut the event from inside of itself...)

But i tried with that "unbind" of the class created by the jqueryUI (".ui-selectee")... But it doesn't work...

Some help, please?

thanks

Comment: It would help that you write your code in english, it's hard to understand code when the var aren't understandable for us.

Now for your problem, are you certain that the unbind() method is called? Try using your navigator debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

cancel option added.

this cancel option determine whether cancel or not

```
$("table").selectable({
    filter: "td",    
    cancel: ".unbind", 
    selected: function(){
        // [some td that you want unbind].addClass("unbind");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried, but i complete forgot about something: that if that i put there, lives inside a "selecting" event of the "Selectable" of jQuery UI... So i need to "end it" from the inside of the event

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work with just "addClass('unbind')", so i did: ".removeClass()" and "addClass()" and it finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about only applying selectable to the first row ?

```
$("table tr:first").selectable({
```